# Prove that: $ (a<b<c) \implies (a<\frac{a+b+c}{3}<c) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that: $$ (a<b<c) \implies (a<\frac{a+b+c}{3}<c) $$
I'm having problem proving these implications (I don't know how they're called in English). Can you tell me what I have to read to understand these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$a<b<c\implies 3a=a+a+a<a+b+c$

and $3c=c+c+c>c+b+a$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. How did you come up with $a+a+a<a+b+c$?

Comment: $a\lt b, a\lt c$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven oh, yeah! Thanks.